# getting errors using primeng-api

Tags: angular, primeng

When I'm using PrimeNg in my simple Angular project, I get this build error:

> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration using description file: \package.json (relative path: ./primeng/api/public_api) no extension
>                     Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                     \primeng\api\public_api doesn't exist

my dependencies are as simple as these:

```js
          "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^9.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/common": "^9.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/core": "^9.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/forms": "^9.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/router": "^9.0.0-rc.6",
        "primeflex": "^1.0.0",
        "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
        "primeng": "^9.0.0-rc.2",
        "rxjs": "~6.5.3",
        "tslib": "^1.10.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
        "@angular/cli": "^9.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.0-rc.6",
        "@angular/language-service": "^9.0.0-rc.6",
        "@ngtools/webpack": "^8.3.20",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "angular-ide": "^0.9.70",
        "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
        "i": "^0.3.6",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~4.3.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
        "npm": "^6.13.4",
        "protractor": "~5.4.2",
        "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
        "tslint": "~5.18.0",
        "typescript": "~3.6.4"
      }
```

This only occurs when I start using some of the `PrimeNg` components, like Toaster or even Panel. Usually things that require prime-api things.

What am I doing wrong? Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized I needed to add the MessageService as Provided in the Component class instead of the Module. With that change, the error was gone.